# Spring Boot Cloud Native Buildpacks on Heroku?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku

I configured my Spring Boot project to use cloud Native Buildpacks to build its docker image as below:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>my-image</name>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The resulting Docker image works fine, but I would like to deploy it on Heroku.
I pushed it to the Heroku Container Registry and tried to release it as explained below:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#releasing-an-image

When I run:

```
heroku container:release web --app my-app
```

I get the following error:

```
▸    Expected response to be successful, got 404
```

By googling the error, it seems that it is due to the fact that the resulting Docker image uses
`ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` to start the application, as explained in the links below:

- https://github.com/grandnode/grandnode/issues/563
- https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1081
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime

Is it possible to configure the Spring Boot Buildpack in order to use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`? Or any other solution to deploy the resulting Docker image on Heroku?